# Use worksheet name as a variable in a lookup

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have 2 workbooks with 60 plus worksheets. I need to copy data from one workbook to the other but would like to capture and use the worksheet name within the cell.
This is because when I create the workbook I make a master worksheet and then copy it 60 plus times. The above would make the cell ref for each worksheet the corresponding worksheet cell in the other file.

Comment: Thanks, I can get the sheetname using similar to the above. I don't know how to use it in a command/formula that then lets me ref it in a cell that I want to copy data from a different workbook having a worksheet with the same sheetnames!

Comment: I don’t understand what you are saying.  If you want help, please edit your question to more clearly explain what your problem is.  Examples might be useful.

Comment: I have a workbook with 60 worksheets which contain 4 rows of data. Each worksheet is simply named 1,2,3...60. I create worksheet 1 and then use a macro to automatically create worksheets 2 to 60. To help with data entry I want to create a copy of the workbook to enter 2 of the 4 rows of data, then in the master workbook copy the data from each of the worksheets from the second workbook. My problem is if I have a copy ref in worksheet 1, when I run the macro to create 2..60 it still copies the data from worksheet 1!. Hope this helps.

Comment: I’m still not sure what you’re saying, but I have a guess.

Comment: Thanks Scott, you have it absolutely correct with what I am trying to do. However I keep getting #Ref!. I have also tried using =INDIRECT(‘[Book2.xls]1’!$I$21) as a step but this also does not work. When entering the INDIRECT function the answer shows as ‘volatile’ and returns #Ref! Maybe I have the syntax wrong, I am using cell AA13 for the worksheet name and the first cell I want to copy data from Book2 is in cell I21. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have `Book2.xls` open while you are working with `Master.xls`? That’s required when you’re using `INDIRECT`.

Comment: Thanks Scott, Yes Book2.xls is open. It is a macro-enabled workbook .xlsm but don't think that matters. If you have Book2 open and go through inserting the INDIRECT function you get the 'volatile' and #Ref! errors as described above. The 'volatile' is due to 'a changing value', some help suggests disabling manual calc but I have tried and it still does not work. Have you got the INDIRECT function as you explained in your answer working? Is it possible for you to list the INDIRECT function using the cells AA13 & I21 incase I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Again, I’m having trouble understanding you –– in particular, whatever you are saying/asking about cells AA13 & I21. To answer your question: yes, I got my answer working (in Excel 2007) and copy & pasted it into Super User. If I click on a cell in `Master.xls` and then click on the _fx_ button (to the left of the formula bar), it says the value is volatile, but if I just look at the cell, it displays the referenced value from `Book2.xls`. ... (more) ...

Comment: ... (continued) ... Have you tried using “Evaluate Formula” to see exactly where it is failing? If you put `=INDIRECT("[Book2.xls]Sheet42!R17C19", FALSE)`, `=INDIRECT("[Book2.xls]Sheet42!S17")`, or `=[Book2.xls]Sheet42!S17` into a cell in `Master.xls`, what happens?

Comment: Thanks for your help Scott, as soon as I put in the INDIRECT function it displays 'volatile' and #Ref! I am using Excel-2010 and the workbooks are .xlsm

Comment: I don’t understand what could be going wrong. We may have reached the point where you need to ask a new question, focusing on that aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The Question

I’m guessing that you have two workbooks (i.e., Microsoft Excel `.xls` spreadsheet files);
let’s call them `Master.xls` and `Book2.xls`.  And `[Master.xls]Sheet1` contains

```
              A                       B                       C
1   =[Book2.xls]Sheet1!A1   =[Book2.xls]Sheet1!B1   =[Book2.xls]Sheet1!C1   ...
2   =[Book2.xls]Sheet1!A2   =[Book2.xls]Sheet1!B2   =[Book2.xls]Sheet1!C2   ...
```

and the problem is that,
when you create `[Master.xls]Sheet2` as a copy of `[Master.xls]Sheet1`, it also gets

```
              A                       B                       C
1   =[Book2.xls]Sheet1!A1   =[Book2.xls]Sheet1!B1   =[Book2.xls]Sheet1!C1   ...
2   =[Book2.xls]Sheet1!A2   =[Book2.xls]Sheet1!B2   =[Book2.xls]Sheet1!C2   ...
```

but you want the cells in `[Master.xls]Sheet2` to be referencing `[Book2.xls]Sheet2` rather than `[Book2.xls]Sheet1`.

#### The Answer

Establish a “helper cell”; let’s say `Z1` – somewhere that’s out of the way. 
(You don’t *really* need to have this “helper cell”,
but things will be much messier if you don’t.) 
Fill it with a formula that evaluates to the name of the current sheet, as documented in
[Is it possible to get the sheetname?](https://superuser.com/q/219481/150988), such as

```
=MID(CELL("filename"), FIND("]",CELL("filename"))+1, 256)
```

Then set the cells in `Master.xls` to

```
=INDIRECT("[Book2.xls]" & $Z$1 & "!R" & ROW() & "C" & COLUMN(),  FALSE)
```

#### Explanation

`[Master.xls]Sheet42!Z1` evaluates to `Sheet42`, so,
in every cell in `[Master.xls]Sheet42`,
the first two terms of the first argument to `INDIRECT`
will evaluate to `[Book2.xls]Sheet42`. 
And, in cell `S17` (for example) of any sheet,
`ROW()` will evaluate to `17` and `COLUMN()` will evaluate to `19`,
and so the last four terms add up to `!R17C19`. 
Put it all together and you’ve got

```
=INDIRECT("[Book2.xls]Sheet42!R17C19",  FALSE)
```

When the second argument to `INDIRECT` is `FALSE`,
it interprets strings like `R17C19` to mean `S17`;
so this is equivalent to

```
=INDIRECT("[Book2.xls]Sheet42!S17")
```

which is equivalent to

```
=[Book2.xls]Sheet42!S17
```